# Invalid attribute name xmlns:xsl1 while validation XSL in Saxon XSLT parser

Tags: xslt, attributes, saxon

We have been using Xalan for XSL transformations for quiet a while and recently moved over to Saxon for XSL transformation.Currently I am using Saxon PE (9.5 version) for XSL transformations 1.0 version (Backward Compatibility mode). Although I am facing difficulties while validating a XSL which came up to me contains a attribute named as shown below.

```
 <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:xsl1">
       <xsl:value-of select="check"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

While validating the XSL i get the error "Error message: Invalid attribute name: {xmlns:xsl1}" although the same validates in Xalan .

Now my question is the name of the attribute valid in this case . Please explain ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It violates this rule in the XSLT 2.0 specification:

[ERR XTDE0860] In the case of an xsl:attribute instruction with no namespace attribute, it is a non-recoverable dynamic error if the effective value of the name attribute is a lexical QName whose prefix is not declared in an in-scope namespace declaration for the xsl:attribute instruction.

(Careful reading of the data model reveals that "xmlns" is not declared in an in-scope namespace declaration, although "xml" is.)

More pertinently, you can't use xsl:attribute to create a namespace declaration: you need to use xsl:namespace for this purpose.

Xalan is following the rules in XSLT 1.0. This is less explicit that this case is an error, but it does say "If the namespace attribute is not present, then the QName is expanded into an expanded-name using the namespace declarations in effect for the xsl:attribute element, not including any default namespace declaration." which in my view carries the implication that if the prefix is not declared, an error results.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a valid attribute name. `xmlns` is a reserved prefix that is used for specifying namespace declarations.